# When An Input Element Has Focus In A Specific Context, Fire An Event On Use Of the Enter/Return Key - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, focus

I have a form that has multiple image components inside it that are outputted onto the page with a `while` loop. When the form is submitted after the image details have been added they are uploaded to a MySQL database via PHP (along with some usage of the JavaScript fetch API to prevent a hard page refresh).

Because of the design of the form I've used multiple image components inside one form instead of having multiple forms: this is so the user can upload multiple images and can do the final submission all in one go (a far better user experience).

**The Problem**

Because the components also each have an individual delete button so that the individual images can be deleted prior to the final set of images being uploaded, this currently has an unwanted side effect: when a user hits the 'enter/return' key on a keyboard, the browser goes to the nearest submit button in the form, which is the delete button for that particular component.

What I want to do is have it so if the 'Image Title' input field is in focus, and the user presses the 'return' key, it defaults to the main image submission button at the very bottom of the form with the class `.upload-details-submit`. It's not an issue with the `<textarea>` element because hitting return when that is in focus just takes you down a line inside the `<textarea>` field and obviously if the 'delete' button has focus then hitting return will carry out the desired action of deleting the image component.

**My Question**

The question I have is essentially two-fold:

a) Is there away to fix this with the HTML `tabindex` attribute?

b) If not, and I have to use JavaScript, what is the best way to approach this? I understand you can use the `.hasFocus()` property on an element to check if it has focus, but how would I go about triggering certain events when the user has given the input element (the Image Title input) focus? Or more specifically when they have filled in the 'Image Title' field and hit the return key, it ignores the nearest 'Delete' button and fires the main `.upload-details-submit` button ?

I have included my JavaScript as well, but I can't seem to get this to work.

**HTML**

```
<form class="upload-form-js" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
        <!-- IMAGE DETAILS COMPONENT. THESE COMPONENTS ARE OUTPUTTED WITH A WHILE LOOP--> 
        
        <div class="upload-details-component">                
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img src="image.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="edit-zone">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="image-title">Image Title</label>
                    <input id="title-title>" class="input-title" type="text" name="image-title[]">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <label for="tags">Comma Separated Image Tags</label>
                    <textarea id="tags" class="text-area" type="text" name="image-tags[]"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->
                    <button name="upload-details-delete" value="12" class="remove-image">DELETE</button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="image-id[]" value="12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- IMAGE DETAILS COMPONENT - END -->

    <div class="form-row upload-details-submit-row">
        <button id="upload-submit" class="upload-details-submit" type="submit" name="upload-submit">COMPLETE UPLOADS</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

**Note:** I'm using a `forEach` loop because although there is only one component in the HTML example above, there will invariably be more than one outputted via the `while` loop on the live site.

```
let inputTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.input-title')

inputTitle.forEach((title) => {
    if (title.hasFocus()) {
        title.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
            if (e.keycode === 13) {
                e.target.closest('form').querySelector('.upload-details-submit').click()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: `if (title.hasFocus()) {` is evaluated once for each `inputTitle` - so the event listener will only be added if that element has focus when this code is run, and it's run only once, so if the focus changes, the event lisetners don't magically get added - move the `if (title.hasFocus()) {` logic INSIDE the event handler

Comment: or, you can add a document keyboard handler that checks which element has the focus when the enter key is pressed - it's the `target` of the event - that would be the simplest code that won't require "hasFocus" at all

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified the HTML for readability (and added a second "component")

Add a `keypress` *handler* to `document`, then check which element is the `target` on the `keypress` - then it's really simple

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.classList.contains('input-title')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.closest('form').querySelector('.upload-details-submit').click()

  }
})

/// just to prevent actual form submission for the answer - you wouldn't do this
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form => form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  console.log('form would submit', e.submitter.id)
  e.preventDefault();
}))
```

```html
<form>

  <div class="upload-details-component">
    <label for="image-title">Image Title</label>
    <input id="title-title" class="input-title" type="text" name="image-title[]">
    <label for="tags">Comma Separated Image Tags</label>
    <textarea id="tags" class="text-area" type="text" name="image-tags[]"></textarea>
    <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->
    <button id='r1' name="upload-details-delete" value="12" class="remove-image">DELETE</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="image-id[]" value="12">
  </div>
  
  <div class="upload-details-component">
    <label for="image-title2">Image Title 2</label>
    <input id="title-title2" class="input-title" type="text" name="image-title[]">
    <label for="tags">Comma Separated Image Tags</label>
    <textarea id="tags2" class="text-area" type="text" name="image-tags[]"></textarea>
    <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->
    <button id='r2' name="upload-details-delete" value="13" class="remove-image">DELETE</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="image-id[]" value="13">
  </div>
  <button id="upload-submit" class="upload-details-submit" type="submit" name="upload-submit">COMPLETE UPLOADS</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

** **update** **

*(This solution works for desktop and touchscreen (mobile) devices)*

My original solution and the solution by @bravo don't support touchscreen keyboards on **mobile** and **tablet devices**. There are ways to solve this (with JS) using:

- `readonly` on textarea
- `disabled` the submit button
- Remove the `submit` attribute on the form.
  Still alot of fiddling about will be needed.

I think the best approach for solving this is to toggling the `tabindex`

You want to avoid [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) as it's depreciated. Here's the solution with `keydown` and `activeElement`

```js
const uploadSubmit = document.querySelector('#upload-submit')
const form = document.querySelector('#form')
let currentImageTab
let activeElement

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  // Check the input element is the image-title 
  const hasImageTitle = document.activeElement.hasAttribute('data-image-title')
  if (hasImageTitle) {
    // The current component

    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      /* 
       ** Only using click for testing on SO ** 
       */
      uploadSubmit.click()
      e.preventDefault()

      /*  
        Use `form.submit()` instead of `uploadSubmit.click()` as it is 
        less hacky and less  prone to any propagation issues.
        Submit will submit the form but will not fire the submit event */
      // form.submit() 
    } else if (e.key === 'Tab') {
      // Re-enables tab
      e.preventDefault()
      currentImageTab.focus()
    }

  }
})

// Gets the tab element of the component
const getTab = () => document.activeElement.closest('[data-upload-details-component]')
  .querySelector('[data-tab]')


document.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  // Updates current image tab

  if (document.activeElement.hasAttribute('data-image-title')) {
    // Each new image title is updated
    currentImageTab = getTab()
    // This prevents textarea being jumped to
    currentImageTab.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1')
  } else {
    // This re-enables textarea to be focus-able. 
    // Dosen't have to until the current image title has been accessed
    if (currentImageTab) {
      currentImageTab.removeAttribute('tabindex')
    }
  }
}, true)

// Use the click event or attributes to manage the behavior of delete  

/*
 Just as @bravo's example, this is just for testing, not required 
*/
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div>Form submitted</div>`)
})
```

```html
<form id="form" class="upload-form-js" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- IMAGE DETAILS COMPONENT. THESE COMPONENTS ARE OUTPUTTED WITH A WHILE LOOP-->
  <div class="upload-details-component" data-upload-details-component>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <!-- <img src="image.jpg"> uncomment -->
    </div>
    <div class="edit-zone">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="image-title">Image Title</label>
        <input data-image-title id="title-title" class="input-title" type="text" name="image-title[]">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="tags">Comma Separated Image Tags</label>
        <textarea data-tab id="tags" class="text-area" type="text" name="image-tags[]"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->
        <button data-delete name="upload-details-delete" value="12" class="remove-image">DELETE</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="image-id[]" value="12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- IMAGE DETAILS COMPONENT - END -->
  <div class="form-row upload-details-submit-row">
    <button id="upload-submit" class="upload-details-submit" type="submit" name="upload-submit">COMPLETE UPLOADS</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it. Also in your example, when you hit the enter key when you've typed into the input title element, it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Fair enough. So yes it has the title-title id. Initially I didn't add the submit functionality because the original submit solution appeared to be working fine, the main problem was the focus jump.

In the end both the leading solution and my solution didn't support mobile or touch devices.

So I made an update to solve this.